# The constructor Geocoder() is undefined

Tags: android

I keep getting the Geocoder as being undefined with the following code.  I am trying to simply get the address of a place from the lat and long.  The line Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH); always comes back as undifined.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
    LocationManager mlocManager =
    (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 600000, 1000, mlocListener);

/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
loc.getLatitude();
loc.getLongitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
currentLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
currentLongitude = loc.getLongitude();

try {
      List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, 1);

      if(addresses != null) {
       Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
       StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
       for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
       }
       myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
      }
      else{
       myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
      }
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is undefined: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html shows you the 2 constructors. One takes a Context, the other takes a Context and a Locale, but crucially you are creating it inside the `MyLocationListener` class. Try using this:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(<ACTIVITY CLASS NAME>.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

instead.

For performance reasons you may want to create a single instance of the `Geocoder` and in the constructor for the `MyLocationListener` class, rather than spawning one every time you get a location update.

Comment: I am still a little confused, what would <ACTIVITY CLASS NAME> be in my specific case?

Comment: Yes it worked great.  Now I am looking how to read a comma delimited file in android.  First I have to know where to locate it so the app can read it.  I could just transfer the data in the comma delimited file to a series of arrays in the sting or java file but there must be a way to just put the comma delimited file in there and read it.  Plus the comma delimited file has like 3000 entries, not many bits as it is text but would be a lot of typing.